# When plotting phase plane portraits are constants considered equal?

Tags: differential-equations, phase-diagram

The phase plane representation of the system, [x';y']=[1,-1;3,-1][x;y], would be concentric ellipses about the Eigen vectors. But, in the case that the constants C1 and C2 are different, can't these ellipses be circles, or just about any ellipse about its axes? couldn't the diagram contain all sorts of flexed versions of the same general shape that aren't at all proportional? I guess what I am asking is whether or not these diagrams are conventionally drawn to describe the basic relationship between the solutions considering only the Eigen value and Eigenvectors (so C1 = C2), or whether my understanding of phase plane portraits is wrong altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to such a linear system, for eigenvalues $r_1$ and $r_2$, with respective eigenvectors $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$, is

$$\vec{x}(t)=C_1\vec{v_1}e^{r_1t}+C_2\vec{v_2}e^{r_2t}$$

At time $t=0$, we see that $x(0)=C_1\vec{v_1}+C_2\vec{v_2}$. The constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ only determine your starting point for drawing a curve in a phase portrait. The eigenvalues $r_1$ and $r_2$ are what actually determine the major and minor axes of the ellipse. The resulting curve in phase space is the same for any pair $(C_1,C_2)$ that starts on the same ellipse.